# How do I define a type which encapsulates/describes the behaviour/signature of a specific module?

Tags: python, mypy

How do I define a type which encapsulates/describes the behaviour/signature of a specific module?

The problem originates from the fact that I *have* to sleep in my code and I want to abstract this away. I want to inject a mock for the `time` library (It's quite likely I want other functions from `time` later on) and I also want to define types as to enable static type checking ([MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) is used for type checking). I'd also like my IDE to have proper autocompletion and documentation (which would the case if it can guess the 'type' correctly)

I currently have the following code which works and passes my checks, however this just ignores the MyPy error (time is not a valid type):

```
import time
[other relevant imports]
...

@dataclass
class RPUService:
    config: RPUConfig
    _time: time = time  # type: ignore[valid-type]
    ...

    def some_method(self):
         self._time.sleep(self.config.sleepytime)
```

I can also write the `_time` definition as follows:

```
from types import ModuleType
_time: ModuleType = time
```

Or similarly with `Any`:

```
from typing import Any
_time: Any = time
```

These are both valid, but this removes my IDE's ability to recognize `self._time` as being the `time` library. (Or something which looks like the `time` library)

I could define a `Protocol` with the signature of `time.sleep` but I'd rather not have the overhead of maintaining such a `Protocol`. [(PEP-544)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#modules-as-implementations-of-protocols)

So my question, how do I define a type which encapsulates/describes the behaviour of a specific module?

(If anything is unclear, please ask)

Comment: Your IDE's capability to auto-complete your code has nothing to do with mypy. I guess `_time = time` is easy to follow for the IDE, but at declaring `_time` to be of a certain type, this information has higher precedence than the definition `= time`, thus it does no longer get auto-completed as `time`, but as "object of the declared type".

Comment: I would go for the protocol approach. That seems like the exact thing you need: "something that has a sleep method which takes one float argument". You dont even have to define all functions of the time module but just the ones you need.

Comment: @Wombatz Hmm, well for now I do only need "something that sleeps" so the protocol would be trivial to create, however, it also hides all other functionality from ```time```. So if, down the road, a colleague wants to use functionality from ```time```, he/she would need to know to extend the protocol, which might not be as straight forward as I'd like. If there's an option to do this without the extra abstraction a protocol brings, I'd prefer such an option.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch The IDE probably does infer the type from assignment to provide auto-completion if the type isn't specified, and one way to make this work (have autocompletion and no MyPy errors) is to remove typing completely. (```_time = time``` is an invalid declaration with ```@dataclass``` though, I'd have to write the ```__init__``` by hand). This is a solution, however, I'd like to learn how to 'solve' this with static typing.

Comment: Is there any need to annotate the type at all? If you want autocomplete and your IDE does autocomplete without annotation, then what is your reason to do that? The only "good" annotations I can imagine for that case would be something like `_time: get_annotation(time)`, but such functionality does not exist. Also you don't want "something that has the signatures of the `time` module", but you want "the `time` module", so why annotate it explicitly, if it always is the same object anyway?